# ruby on rails: ancestry not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

i'm using ancestry gem to build a hierarchy tree. I installed the gem, and I can select a node has a parent, but when I do for example this `<% @posts.root.children.each do |page| %>` it gives me

```
`undefined method `root' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x7094790>`
```

What am I doing wrong?

In the post model I have "has_ancestry". And I have the column ancestry in the database too

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have an `ActiveRecord::Relation` not an instance of `Post`

`Post.find(1).root.children` for example would work (assuming you have a post with an id of 1 in the database)

Comment: yes that way it works, but how can I list my posts and its children using that method ?

Comment: loop through `@posts`

Comment: @terrorista you might want to check `arrange` method on [github](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#arrangement)